# How to break a long equation with left indentation

Tags: equations

[image: Dar]

I need to write a similar equation which needs to be split such that left side is left aligned and right comes exactly under it .. will appreciate the help
regards.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I suggest you (a) use an `align*` environment and (b) place the alignment character `&` at the start of each line:

```
\begin{align*}
& \Lambda(r\mid \psi, H) = \\
& \frac{1}{(...
\end{align*}
```

Comment: It helped . but the equation number doesn't update in align* environment, so I used it inside the equation environment and then used aligned i.e.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \Lambda(r\mid \psi, H) = \\
& \frac{1}{(...
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: @Shia - Your write-up and screenshot didn't feature equation numbers; that's why I assumed you were interested in unnumbered equation systems. To assign a single equation number to the entire system, use either `\begin{equation} \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} \end{equation}` [as you mentioned in your comment] or `\begin{equation} \begin{split} ... \end{split} \end{equation}`.